# What significance does `...` serve following a parameter type?

Tags: java, types, parameters

I am currently trying to get AsyncTasks working in Android, and have found something I have never seen before over and over again in many different tutorials.

Certain methods in the tutorials are passed parameters that look like this `String... arg0`, `Integer... values`.

[`Here`](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/) is a tutorial with some code shown similar to what I am describing.

What does this mean? Why is the `...` there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called varargs. It works for any type as long as it's the *last* argument in the signature.

Basically, any number of parameters are put into an array. This does not mean that it is equivalent to an array.

A method that looks like:

```
void foo(int bar, Socket baz...)
```

will have an *array* of Socket (in this example) called baz.

So, if we call `foo(32, sSock.accept(), new Socket())` we'll find an array with two Socket objects.

Calling it as `foo(32, mySocketArray)` will **not** work. However, if the signature is a varargs of arrays you can pass one or more arrays and get a two-dimensional array. For example, `void bar(int bar, PrintStream[] baz...)` can take multiple arrays of PrintStream and stick them into a single `PrintStream[][]`.